# ES Lint rule for chained then promise calls

Tags: es6-promise, eslint

I am searching for an ES Lint rule that will force the following behavior:

```
aPromiseCall()
   .then(() => {
       // logic
   })
   .then(() => {
       // logic
   })
   .catch(() => {

   })
```

Notice that each `.then` should be indented by 4 spaces and on a . separate line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following rule:

`"indent": ["error", 4, { "MemberExpression": 1 }]`

> "MemberExpression" (default: 1) enforces indentation level for multi-line property chains. This can also be set to "off" to disable checking for MemberExpression indentation.

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent#memberexpression